# React Select All for multiple checkboxes

Tags: reactjs, checkbox, react-hooks, use-state, selectall

```js
import React, { useState, useEffect } from "react";
import "./styles.css";

export default function App() {
  const [checkedAll, setCheckedAll] = useState(false);
  const [checked, setChecked] = useState({
    nr1: false,
    nr2: false
  });

  /* ################################################ */
  /* #### TOGGLES checK STATE BASED ON inputName #### */
  /* ################################################ */

  const toggleCheck = (inputName) => {
    setChecked((prevState) => {
      const newState = { ...prevState };
      newState[inputName] = !prevState[inputName];
      return newState;
    });
  };

  /* ###################################################### */
  /* #### CHECKS OR UNCHECKS ALL FROM SELECT ALL CLICK #### */
  /* ###################################################### */

  const selectAll = (value) => {
    setCheckedAll(value);
    setChecked((prevState) => {
      const newState = { ...prevState };
      for (const inputName in newState) {
        newState[inputName] = value;
      }
      return newState;
    });
  };

  /* ############################################# */
  /* #### EFFECT TO CONTROL CHECKED_ALL STATE #### */
  /* ############################################# */

  // IF YOU CHECK BOTH INDIVIDUALLY. IT WILL ACTIVATE THE checkedAll STATE
  // IF YOU UNCHECK ANY INDIVIDUALLY. IT WILL DE-ACTIVATE THE checkAll STATE

  useEffect(() => {
    let allChecked = true;
    for (const inputName in checked) {
      if (checked[inputName] === false) {
        allChecked = false;
      }
    }
    if (allChecked) {
      setCheckedAll(true);
    } else {
      setCheckedAll(false);
    }
  }, [checked]);

  /* ########################## */
  /* #### RETURN STATEMENT #### */
  /* ########################## */

  return (
    <div className="App">
      <div>
        <label>All</label>
        <input
          type="checkbox"
          onChange={(event) => selectAll(event.target.checked)}
          checked={checkedAll}
        />
      </div>
      <div>
        <label>1</label>
        <input
          type="checkbox"
          name="nr1"
          onChange={() => toggleCheck("nr1")}
          checked={checked["nr1"]}
        />
      </div>
      <div>
        <label>2</label>
        <input
          type="checkbox"
          name="nr2"
          onChange={() => toggleCheck("nr2")}
          checked={checked["nr2"]}
        />
      </div>
    </div>
  );
}
```

I wish to create a Select All Checkbox functionality as shown in the following code:
https://codesandbox.io/s/festive-framework-8l2ez?file=/src/App.js

How can I use the above code for an array of checkboxes? I believe that it can be sorted out using map but I'm not able to implement it.
In the above code, the value is being set for nr1 and nr2 separately.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can just have an array at the top to define checkboxes and create the initial state. Then loop into the array to display the checkboxes. Try below code

```
const dataArray = ['nr1', 'nr2'];
const initialState = dataArray.reduce((o, key) => ({ ...o, [key]: false}), {})

export default function App() {
  const [checkedAll, setCheckedAll] = useState(false);
  const [checked, setChecked] = useState(initialState);

 ...
 ...
return (
    <div className="App">
      <div>
        <label>All</label>
        <input
          type="checkbox"
          onChange={(event) => selectAll(event.target.checked)}
          checked={checkedAll}
        />
      </div>
        {dataArray.map(data => (
          <div>
        <label>{data}</label>
        <input
          type="checkbox"
          name={data}
          onChange={() => toggleCheck(data)}
          checked={checked[data]}
          />
      </div>
        ))}
    </div>
  );
```